# magento fishpig wordpress integration - block view of non-magento blog site

Tags: wordpress, magento, blogs, fishpig

I've gotten the 4.3.08 fishpig extension working with my 1.7 Magento site (yes, I know it's a very old magento version). The integrated blog looks great and has the magento theme when I access it via the Site Address URL. However, I can still access the non-integrated blog when I type the Wordpress URL into a browser. That url doesn't have the integrated theme - it's just the plain posts. I don't want google to index that wordpress url or for users to find that url. I want them to only see the Site Address URL. I have done a ton of searches but can't seem to find how to do this. Looking for help!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included your URL so I can't provide accurate feedback. That being said, if configured correctly, the WordPress URL should give a 404 error page. This won't be seen by anyone and won't be indexed by search engines.

If the WordPress URL is visible and everything is configured correctly, you may be using the default permalinks (eg. /blog/?p=123). Change the Permalink structure at Settings > Permalinks and the WordPress URL should generate a 404 page.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

www.randalldesigns.net/randall-design-blog and www.randalldesigns.net/blog - you'd responded directly to me via email, and I'm still stuck, so i thought I'd widen the net. But it looks like it came back to you again. I'm about to move the wordpress install to a different folder to see if that resolves it.

Comment: From looking at your URL, I can see you're using the standard permalinks (eg. /blog/?p=123). When WordPress is configured this way, the /wp URL displays the post list. To fix this, select a different permalink structure at Settings > Permalinks and the /wp URL will become a 404 page. I'll update my answer above.